# How to compare if the new date is after the old date in android

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to see how I can compare if the new date is after the old date if so no data will be shown from the firebase database. I am having trouble with this because my app crashes when I test it I believe I'm doing something wrong. Can someone help me with this issues? Below is my code. Thanks in advance

```
 //Code
    
    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);



                        for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                            UserInformation2 upload=postsnapshot.getValue(UserInformation2.class);


                            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd-yyyy");
                            //String now = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());

                           Date d=new Date();
                            String AdCreationDate = postsnapshot.child("created").getValue(String.class);
                            //SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")

                            try {

                                Date new_date = simpleDateFormat.parse(String.valueOf(d));
                                Date old_date = simpleDateFormat.parse(AdCreationDate);


                                if(new_date.after(old_date)){
                                    // Your time expired do your logic here.
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Your data expired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }else{
                                    myUploads.add(upload);

                                    recyclerView.invalidate();
                                }

                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            //simpleDateFormat.format(d);
                           //Date e=new Date(old);












                        }

                        linearLayoutWithoutItems.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Stacktrace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.tout, PID: 22667
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:638)
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on `String old = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(Date.parse(AdCreationDate)));`, what is the value of `AdCreationDate`?

Comment: @algorhythm the AdcreationDate is the date it was created

Comment: Yeah looks like it is throwing an illegal argument exception though so it is not in the expected format. Try adding `System.out.println(AdCreationDate)` just before line 638 to see what it looks like in the console

Comment: @algorhythm I updated my code. I made some changes and I ran the app. the app no longer crashes but its just a blank page. What can be the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

Your error isn't in the comparison, it's in the `String old = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(Date.parse(AdCreationDate)));`

Check the value of `AdCreationDate` it might not be compatible with a list of valid date formats that can be parsed, at the very least you can place `AdCreationDate` into a `SimpleDateFormat` and then parse that.

Comment: the  adcreation is actually the date it was created

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this logic. When working with dates it's always better to work with `timestamp`. This is easy to convert to date or anything else and also easy to compare between dates.

So, when you are saving your date to the database just save it as

```
long timestamp = date.getTime(); //this will return time in milliseconds
```

Then when you retreive the values from database, you don't even have to format them before checking which one is older. You can simply use this:

```
long database_timestamp = postsnapshot.child("created").getValue();
long current_timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (current_timestamp > database_timestamp) //this will check if current_timestamp has greater value then database_timestamp, if it has it means that it's date from later in time
```

Now you can simply convert that to date and use SimpleDateFormat to format it as you want:

```
Date new_date = new Date(current_timestamp); 
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormaT("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

This also covers each hour, second, minut,e or anything else you need. So, this will also check if the current date is greater than the other one even if there is only a few seconds difference between them. Which means your data will be live. If you don't need this you can also avoid it by setting the hour, minutes, and seconds on the `Date` to 0.

Comment: where did you get date.getTime from?

Comment: If you want a current timestamp from some date object, you can use the date.getTime(). Let's say you have a date in your code like this: Date login_date = new Date(); this will create a date object with the current time, then you can use login_date.getTime() to get timestamp or time in milliseconds. But if you don't have a date you can simply use System.currentTimeMillis(); to get a timestamp from the current date. This changes the whole logic of your program, you first need to edit date fields in your database for this to work.

Comment: Working with timestamp instead of string dates is way better, faster and easier.

Comment: ok. I will try this right now. I'll tell you if it works

Comment: hi, I tried your answer it somewhat works. But Its deleting all of the data in the database firebase it should only delete the one where the date is from later in time

Comment: How are you updating data? You are probably doing something wrong and overwritting existing data. Be sure that your database reference is pointing to the field you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is actually related to

`Date new_date = simpleDateFormat.parse(String.valueOf(d));`

If you comment out that line and then update the if statement to

```
if(d.after(old_date)){
```

You don't need to parse the new date as it's already a Date object. You only need to parse the date from your snapshot as it is a string.

I'd also change the new date variable `d` to something more meaningful as it well help the readability of the code and the Java standard for naming variables is to use camel case where the scond word is capitalised without an underscore i.e. 'oldDate'. It's good to get into the habit of following these conventions.